# Are there any spell checkers and thesaurus programs that can be run locally as OEM?

Tags: spell-check, oem, api, localization, thesaurus

I don't usually handle such things, but I've recently been tasked to compile a list of possible spell checkers that we can buy as OEM to integrate with our own SaaS analytics programs.

The problem is, I have NO idea what to try next! There's plenty of spell check APIs out there, but the project lead was quite insistent that any product must be run locally for privacy reasons, and as such making calls to a distant API server is not allowed. I was told that there "are definitely loads of those services on offer", and "if you can't find them, you're looking in the wrong place".

Great. But I *can't* find them, and I have no idea where to look. I've done the Google Fu, I've looked through API aggregate websites, but none of them allow for running/executing the services locally.

Can you guys help me and/or point me in the right direction? Where should I even start?

With kind regards,
JFA